# Crystal report viewer on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to make report with crystal report viewer on vb.net but how to select records by date and time

`" like from 7:00 pm of yesterday to 7:00 am of today "`

Thank you for help

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: what are you done still now, show us your vb.net code or sql query.  For sql-query you simply use `yourDateColumn  between GetDate()-1 and GetDate()